# javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var siteurl = window.location;
var patt= /(http:\/\/)(www.)*([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]*)(.*)/i;
```

Now i want to get value of $3, how to?

Comment: See my comment about hostname.  Also, keep in mind that your regex is very simple and would break easily: `https://ok.im.here.com/`.  Notice the protocol and the multi-sub-domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RegExp.$3
```

You may want to consider not using `window.location`, though.  Using one of the following would make your RegExp simpler and avoid the need to test for different protocols (eg https, ftp, etc):

```
window.location.host
window.location.hostname
```

#### Examples

---

- option 1 - window.location

  ```
  var siteurl = window.location;
  var patt= /(http:\/\/)(www.)*([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]*)(.*)/i;


  siteurl.match(patt);
  alert(RegExp.$3);
  ```
- option 2 - window.location.hostname

  ```
  var siteurl = window.location.hostname;
  var patt= /(www.)*([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]*)/i;


  siteurl.match(patt);
  alert(RegExp.$2);
  ```

#### Edits

---

As noted, this method is [deprecated](http://www.georgehernandez.com/h/xComputers/JavaScript/Objects/RegExp.asp), but not yet removed in JS 1.5.  It is still available for you to use.

The only thing you need to be aware of is modifying the `.lastIndex` property if you will be using multiple times so that the object doesn't wrap.

Comment: According to MDC, that's deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_Features#RegExp_Methods

Comment: **@Pointy:** yes it still works.  **@idealmachine:** yes you are also correct.  -- I've included a note as I think that is worth mentioning.  I don't think this was worth a `-1`; deprecated != unavailable and as the MDC says, it is still used in `replace()`.  You can test it yourself if you think it won't work.

Comment: Well before you added the "Example" part, it wasn't exactly clear what you meant. I didn't downvote however.

Comment: Tried to get the answer up there fast and the explanation later :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var three = patt.exec(siteurl)[3];
```

The exec method returns an "array" corresponding to the matching elements of the first match. [0] is the entire matched substring, [1] is the text matched by the first capturing group, ... Subsequent calls to exec would return subsequent matches if your regex had the "g" (global) flag set (it does not, and it does not need to).

Note that if you are not sure whether or not the match exists, you should add some error handling:

```
var result = patt.exec(siteurl);
if(result && result[3]) {
    var three = result[3];
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var three = siteurl.replace(patt, "$3");
```

You can also call "exec" on the regex, and that will return an array. The first element (index 0) of the array will be all the text that matched the complete pattern, and then subsequent indexes will contain the values of the capturing groups in the regex.

```
var groups = patt.exec(siteurl);
var three = groups[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not writing a regex for this.

If you want to get the hostname, just do what vol7ron suggests.

If you really do need to parse a URI in JavaScript, take a look at Appendix B of thehttp://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html
and use the match array returned from `myString.match(myRegex)`.

> **Appendix B. Parsing a URI Reference with a Regular Expression**
>
> As the "first-match-wins" algorithm is
>   identical to the "greedy"
>   disambiguation method used by POSIX
>   regular expressions, it is natural and
>   commonplace to use a regular
>   expression for parsing the potential
>   five components of a URI reference.
>
> The following line is the regular
>   expression for breaking-down a
>   well-formed URI reference into its
>   components.
>
> ```
> ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
>
>  12            3  4          5       6  7        8 9
> ```
>
> The numbers in the second line above
>   are only to assist readability; they
>   indicate the reference points for each
>   subexpression (i.e., each paired
>   parenthesis). We refer to the value
>   matched for subexpression
>
> as $.  For example, matching
>   the above expression to
>   http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related
>
> results in the following subexpression
>   matches:
>
> ```
>   $1 = http:
>   $2 = http
>   $3 = //www.ics.uci.edu
>   $4 = www.ics.uci.edu
>   $5 = /pub/ietf/uri/
>   $6 = <undefined>
>   $7 = <undefined>
>   $8 = #Related
>   $9 = Related where <undefined> indicates that the component is not
> ```
>
> present, as is the case for the query
>   component in the above example.
>   Therefore, we can determine the value
>   of the five components as
>
> ```
>   scheme    = $2
>   authority = $4
>   path      = $5
>   query     = $7
>   fragment  = $9
> ```